# The text is getting positioned before the image but I want to the image to come first. Also I used absolute positioning as I want the image at bottom

Tags: html, css, positioning

Here is my code:

```css
.top-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.synth {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <h1>A Heading</h1>
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <img class="synth" src="Synthwave 1.png" alt="Synth">
  <div class="middle-container">
    This is some text
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried removing the absolute position from CSS, but can't position the image at the bottom without it.

Comment: I guess you need to add ```z-index: -1``` in the class ```synth ```.

Answer (score 0):

This is crude and might be on track to what you're looking for.

Absolute positioning is causing the issues you're facing.

Rework the structure and *smooth it out*.

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.synth {
  max-width: 70%;
  background: #a33;
}
```

```html
<div class="top-container">
  <header>
    <div>
      <h1>A Heading</h1>
      <p>Some Text</p>
    </div>
    <img class="synth" src="Synthwave 1.png" alt="Synth">
  </header>
  <div class="middle-container">
    This is some text
  </div>
</div>
```